# Sort object with multiple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

is it possible to sort an object with multiple arrays?

Example:

```
{
 'Michael Schmidt':["Michael Schmidt", "..."],
 'Hans Mustermann': ["Hans Mustermann", "..."],
 'Anton Mustermann': ["Anton Mustermann", "..."]
}
```

I found so much solution how to sort an array of objects but nothing about my issue.

Regards

Solution:

```
  var keys = Object.keys(users),
  len = keys.length;
  keys.sort();
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   var k = keys[i];
 }
```

Comment: This is not valid Javascript. You probably have an array instead of an object (and the names should be strings)?

Comment: please add a valid data structure and the wanted result of the sorting.

Comment: Sorry, did forget to add the keys:D

Comment: You need to explain what should be sorted (and by what criteria).

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't have a notion of order internally, so you can't sort them. Arrays do, you can simply sort an array with a comparator function: `array.sort([compareFunction])`.

Maybe you are looking for a sorted map implementation in JavaScript, in that case, you need to use you own solution (or the implementation of someone else), as plain objects are not suitable for this.

Comment: I found an easy solution:                                                                                                   var keys = Object.keys(users),
      len = keys.length;
  keys.sort();
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];}